# Android studio intellisense cannot resolve symbol on import

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android development and inherited a project from an old collegue. At some point in time, I changed something in the project structure. I'm not sure what I changed that triggered these errors. However, now intellisense shows all kind of errors: Ex. on `import android.content.Intent;` it says *Cannot resolve symbol 'Intent'*.

Now, the project still builds and runs without a problem, however, everywhere in the project are red squiggly lines and autocomplete doesn't work.

I have tried all i could find on this problem (invalidate cache / deleting files / reimport project / etc) The only thing I found to work is changing the API version to 27, in which case every intellisense warning dissappears, although the project breaks, because it uses version 28 stuff.
[image]

Currently, the app module has compileSdkVersion 28 and targetSdkVerion 27. Changing both to 27 resolves the intellisense, but breaks the projct, changing both to 28 (or 29) doesn't resolve anything.

It feels like i might need to update something else?

***update as requested by haresh, ***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nl.app.ofme"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'

//Used to get clear warning details about deprecated methods
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'

        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0@aar'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart ...

Comment: @user1515791 Try a rebuild: Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Comment: I'm thankfull that you are trying to help, but as i state in my question; i already tried that (invalidate cache / deleting files / reimport project)

Comment: @user1515791 make sure you have the right SDK installed: Tools -> SKD Manager -> Download API Level 28 (or 29)

Comment: SDK platform 23 - 29 installed, Tools: Platform-tools 29, SDK tools 26 (but i dont see anything to update that last one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use updated version for all of your module and project level library.
2. File -> Snyc Project with gradle files.
3. Migrate with androidx.  Refactor -> Migrate to Android
4. In Android Studio, go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

This are the all things you can try.

Comment: 2,3 and 4 does nothing. Any tricks or checks for 1? Ive updated android studio as far as possible.

Comment: can you post your project level and module level gradle code.